# When are pure liquids included in the equilibrium constant?

Tags: organic-chemistry, equilibrium

For an esterification reaction of pure liquids only, the equilibrium constant will take into account all species, however for an aqueous based esterification reaction, water is not included in the constant

Why are pure liquids used in the first reaction and pure liquids not used in the second reaction, don't pure liquids have an activity of one hence can't we just assume that the equilibrium constant for the first reaction is one, or do we only exclude pure liquids when they act as a solute or they are present in a heterogeneous equilibrium?

Also note that I have a very vague knowledge of thermodynamics.

Comment: Water is included, you must have heard of water being removed to progress the esterification in the forward reaction.

Comment: Yes but when are pure liquids not included